# Tic Tac Toe Batch Game

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to code a tictactoe game in batch.
But I ran into several problems I can't solve.

1. After the third move of player 1, the game has to check if player 1 has won.
   I tried to do that by making 8 variables of all possible 8 winlines. And then the game checks if any of the winlines equals to XXX or OOO.
   The Problem is that the field variables (_f1, _f2, etc.) don't change to X or O. I set them at the beginning of the script by their numbers, but I dont understand why they dont change once a player put a X or O in that field/variable.
2. The code is very ugly and unnecessarily long. I'm aware of the `for` command and i can do basic loops, but I cant wrap my head around the syntax if the command gets too complicated. How can I put all the repititions in for loops?

   ```
    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    title .:TIC TAC TOE:.
    mode con: cols=40 lines=20
    color 02
    cls



    goto :main

    :check
        if !_win1!==XXX (
            echo END OF GAME
            pause
        )
        if !_win2!==XXX (
            echo END OF GAME
            pause
        )
        if !_win3!==XXX (
            echo END OF GAME
            pause
        )
        if !_win4!==XXX (
            echo END OF GAME
            pause
        )
        if !_win5!==XXX (
            echo END OF GAME
            pause
        )
        if !_win6!==XXX (
            echo END OF GAME
            pause
        )
        if !_win7!==XXX (
            echo END OF GAME
            pause
        )
        if !_win8!==XXX (
            echo END OF GAME
            pause
        )
    goto :eof

    :player2turn
        choice /c 123456789 /n /m "!_player2!, it's your turn!"
        if !errorlevel!==1 (
                if !_f1!==1 (
                    set _f1=!_player2symbol!
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                    )
            )
            if !errorlevel!==2 (
                if !_f2!==2 (
                    set _f2=!_player2symbol!
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                )
            )
            if !errorlevel!==3 (
                if !_f3!==3 (
                    set _f3=!_player2symbol!
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                )
            )
            if !errorlevel!==4 (
                if !_f4!==4 (
                    set _f4=!_player2symbol!
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                )
            )
            if !errorlevel!==5 (
                if !_f5!==5 (
                    set _f5=!_player2symbol!
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                )
            )
            if !errorlevel!==6 (
                if !_f6!==6 (
                    set _f6=!_player2symbol!
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                )
            )
            if !errorlevel!==7 (
                if !_f7!==7 (
                    set _f7=!_player2symbol!
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                )
            )
            if !errorlevel!==8 (
                if !_f8!==8 (
                    set _f8=!_player2symbol!
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                )
            )
            if !errorlevel!==9 (
                if !_f9!==9 (
                    set _f9=!_player2symbol!
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                )
            )
    goto :eof

    :player1turn
        choice /c 123456789 /n /m "!_player1!, it's your turn!"
            if !errorlevel!==1 (
                if !_f1!==1 (
                    set _f1=!_player1symbol!
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                    )
            )
            if !errorlevel!==2 (
                if !_f2!==2 (
                    set _f2=!_player1symbol!
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                )
            )
            if !errorlevel!==3 (
                if !_f3!==3 (
                    set _f3=!_player1symbol!
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                )
            )
            if !errorlevel!==4 (
                if !_f4!==4 (
                    set _f4=!_player1symbol!
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                )
            )
            if !errorlevel!==5 (
                if !_f5!==5 (
                    set _f5=!_player1symbol!
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                )
            )
            if !errorlevel!==6 (
                if !_f6!==6 (
                    set _f6=!_player1symbol!
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                )
            )
            if !errorlevel!==7 (
                if !_f7!==7 (
                    set _f7=!_player1symbol!
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                )
            )
            if !errorlevel!==8 (
                if !_f8!==8 (
                    set _f8=!_player1symbol!
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                )
            )
            if !errorlevel!==9 (
                if !_f9!==9 (
                    set _f9=!_player1symbol!
                    echo !_win1!
                    echo !_player1symbol!
                    pause
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    goto :player1turn
                )
            )
    goto :eof

    ::displaying the map
    :map
        echo.
        echo.
        echo.
        echo           !_f7! ^| !_f8! ^| !_f9!
        echo           ---------
        echo           !_f4! ^| !_f5! ^| !_f6!
        echo           ---------
        echo           !_f1! ^| !_f2! ^| !_f3!
        echo.
        echo.
        echo.
    goto :eof


    ::setting variables
    :setvar
        set _f1=1
        set _f2=2
        set _f3=3
        set _f4=4
        set _f5=5
        set _f6=6
        set _f7=7
        set _f8=8
        set _f9=9

        set _win1=!_f7!!_f8!!_f9!
        set /a _win2=!_f4!+!_f5!+!_f6!
        set /a _win3=!_f1!+!_f2!+!_f3!
        set /a _win4=!_f7!+!_f4!+!_f1!
        set /a _win5=!_f8!+!_f5!+!_f2!
        set /a _win6=!_f9!+!_f6!+!_f3!
        set /a _win7=!_f7!+!_f5!+!_f3!
        set /a _win8=!_f9!+!_f5!+!_f1!
    goto :eof

    ::player settings
    :setup
        echo.
        set /p _player1=Enter name for Player 1: 
        echo.
        choice /c xo /n /m "!_player1! do you want to play as X or O?"
            if !errorlevel!==1 (
                set _player1symbol=X
                set _player2symbol=O
            ) else (
                set _player1symbol=O
                set _player2symbol=X
            )
        echo.
        echo.
        set /p _player2=Enter name for Player 2: 
        echo.
        cls
        echo.
        echo.
        echo.
        echo !_player1!(!_player1symbol!) vs. !_player2!(!_player2symbol!)
        pause>nul
    goto :eof

    :main
    setlocal

        call :setup
        cls
        call :setvar

        call :map
        call :player1turn
        cls
        call :map
        call :player2turn
        cls
        call :map
        call :player1turn
        cls
        call :map
        call :player2turn
        cls
        call :map
        call :player1turn
        call :check


    endlocal
    goto :eof
   ```

Comment: no idea why you would think `||` is valid within `If` syntax, I suggest you read the help output of `If /?` within cmd.exe As for the very general question regarding using for loops for repetative tasks, consider watiching some [youtube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVeW9qkBjo3zosnqUbG7CFw) - Note -Stackoverflow is not a tutorial service for teaching you the syntax of a language or general programming concepts.

Comment: you cannot use conditional operators like this in `if` statements. `if` is expecting a command after it. You're just creating more problems for yourself.

Comment: well ok, if i take the || part and the second if command out of the script, it still doesnt work. if i echo the value of _win1, right after setting _f1, _f2 and _f3 to X, it outputs 789. i just dont get that part

Comment: it won't work, there are loads of other issues. you `win` variables are not what you think they are either. To be honest, it would be easier for me to re-write it for you than having to find and fix your bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution

All i had to do was to set the win variables later, when checking the winlines.

Comment: So it seems like it wasnt hard to fix at all! And it seems like my variables are indeed what i thought they are. And it also seems like there are no "loads" of other issues either.

Answer (score 3):

You should research and define your coding approach before write a single line of program. Also, you should learn the language features in order to make good use of its facilities. This applies to any programming language.

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Test for win: Horizontal rows
set "win[1]=%%pos[1]%%%%pos[2]%%%%pos[3]%%"
set "win[2]=%%pos[4]%%%%pos[5]%%%%pos[6]%%"
set "win[3]=%%pos[7]%%%%pos[8]%%%%pos[9]%%"
rem Test for win: Vertical cols
set "win[4]=%%pos[1]%%%%pos[4]%%%%pos[7]%%"
set "win[5]=%%pos[2]%%%%pos[5]%%%%pos[8]%%"
set "win[6]=%%pos[3]%%%%pos[6]%%%%pos[9]%%"
rem Test for win: Diagonals
set "win[7]=%%pos[1]%%%%pos[5]%%%%pos[9]%%"
set "win[8]=%%pos[7]%%%%pos[5]%%%%pos[3]%%"

for /L %%i in (1,1,9) do set "pos[%%i]=%%i"
set "taken=_"

cls
set /P "player[X]=Enter player 1 (X) name: "
set /P "player[O]=Enter player 2 (O) name: "
call :showBoard

set "players=XO"
for /L %%n in (1,1,9) do (
   call :playerTurn !players:~0,1!
   if !result! equ 1 echo You win^^^! & goto :EOF
   set "players=!players:~1,1!!players:~0,1!"
)
echo Game was a draw...
goto :EOF


:playerTurn wichOne
choice /C 123456789 /N /M "!player[%1]!, it's your turn: "
set "choice=%errorlevel%"
if "!taken:%choice%=!" neq "%taken%" echo Bad position & goto playerTurn
set "taken=%taken%%choice%"
set "pos[%choice%]=%1"
call :showBoard
rem Test if win
set "result=0"
for /L %%i in (1,1,8) do if !result! equ 0 (
   call set "line=!win[%%i]!
   if "!line!" equ "%1%1%1" set "result=1"
)
exit /B


:showBoard
echo/
echo/
echo           %pos[1]% ^| %pos[2]% ^| %pos[3]%
echo           ---------
echo           %pos[4]% ^| %pos[5]% ^| %pos[6]%
echo           ---------
echo           %pos[7]% ^| %pos[8]% ^| %pos[9]%
echo/
echo/
exit /B
```

**EDIT 2021/12/08:** *New version added*

The original version of this program was simple enough to be understand by the OP. The next version below was written with the purpose of be as efficient and short as possible:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "win=" & set "out="
for %%a in (1:2:3 4:5:6 7:8:9  1:4:7 2:5:8 3:6:9  1:5:9 3:5:7) do (
   for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%x in ("%%a") do (
      set "win=!win! ^!pos[%%x]^!^!pos[%%y]^!^!pos[%%z]^!"
      if "!out:~-3,1!" neq "9" set "out=!out!$^!pos[%%x]^! ^^| ^!pos[%%y]^! ^^| ^!pos[%%z]^!"
   )
)
set "out=!out:~1!"

:menu
cls
set /P "player[X]=Enter player 1 (X) name: "
set /P "player[O]=Enter player 2 (O) name: "

for /L %%i in (1,1,9) do set "pos[%%i]=%%i"
set "options=123456789" & set "filler=asdfghjkl"

for %%n in (X O X O X O X O X) do (
   cls
   echo/& echo/& echo     %out:$=& echo     --+---+--& echo     %& echo/& echo/
   choice /C !options! /N /M "!player[%%n]!, it's your turn: "
   for /F "tokens=1,2" %%e in ("!errorlevel! !filler:~0,1!") do (
      set "options=!options:%%e=%%f!" & set "filler=!filler:~1!" & set "pos[%%e]=%%n"
   )
   set "line=%win%"
   if "!line:%%n%%n%%n=!" neq "!line!" echo You win^^^! & goto nextGame
)
echo Game was a draw...
:nextGame
echo/
pause
goto :menu
```

Comment: @Gerhard: I removed the `cls` on purpose so the players can check the board before and after each move.

Comment: Yeah, I am fine with that, as mentioned it is just a "choice" thing :)

Comment: so in the first for command, if ":" is the delimiter, then what do the spaces do??

Comment: The first command is a plain `for` (no /F switch) so you can _not_ define the delimiters. In this case, the standard delimiters are the space, comma, semicolon and equal-sign, so the spaces separate the elements. Is in the _second_ `for /F` command where the ":" is the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

@Aacini posted a great answer, so I decided to post my own as well. As they say, there are many ways to skin a cat.

```
@echo off & Title Tic-Tac-Toe 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & mode con: cols=40 lines=20 & color 02
for /F %%i in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do set "n=%%iE"
:menu
cls & set gone=. & for %%p in (player[X] player[O]) do set /p "%%~p=enter name %%p: "
for /l %%i in (1,1,9) do set a%%i=%%i
for /L %%i in (1,1,4) do for %%a in (X O) do (
      for %%x in (!a1!!a2!!a3! !a4!!a5!!a6! !a7!!a8!!a9! !a1!!a4!!a7! !a2!!a5!!a8! !a3!!a6!!a9! !a1!!a5!!a9! !a3!!a5!!a7!) do (
          if "%%x" == "!_h!!_h!!_h!" echo !pl! wins & timeout /t 4 /NOBREAK >nul & goto :menu
      )
          set "pl=!player[%%a]!" & set _h=%%a
          call :play
          set "a!ch!=%%a"
          if %%i geq 4 echo No winners & timeout /t 4 /NOBREAK >nul & goto :menu
 )

:play
cls & echo(
echo     !a1! ^| !a2! ^| !a3!%n%    ----------%n%    !a4! ^| !a5! ^| !a6!%n%    ----------%n%    !a7! ^| !a8! ^| !a9!%n%
choice /c 123456789 /m "!pl!'s turn"
set ch=!errorlevel!
if !ch! equ 0 exit /b
if "!gone:%ch%=!" neq "%gone%" echo That spot has been taken, try again & timeout /t 3 /NOBREAK >nul & goto :play
set "gone=%gone%!ch!"
goto :eof
```

And a version for older windows that does not support VT100:

```
@echo off & Title Tic-Tac-Toe 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & mode con: cols=40 lines=20 & color 02
:menu
cls & set gone=. & for %%p in (player[X] player[O]) do set /p "%%~p=enter name %%p: "

for /l %%i in (1,1,9) do set a%%i=%%i
for /L %%i in (1,1,4) do for %%a in (X O) do (
      for %%x in (!a1!!a2!!a3! !a4!!a5!!a6! !a7!!a8!!a9! !a1!!a4!!a7! !a2!!a5!!a8! !a3!!a6!!a9! !a1!!a5!!a9! !a3!!a5!!a7!) do (
          if "%%x" == "!_h!!_h!!_h!" echo !pl! wins & timeout /t 4 /NOBREAK >nul & goto :menu
      )
          set "pl=!player[%%a]!" & set _h=%%a
          call :play
          set "a!ch!=%%a"
          if %%i geq 4 echo No winners & timeout /t 4 /NOBREAK >nul & goto :menu
 )

:play
cls & echo(
echo    !a1! ^| !a2! ^| !a3!&echo    ----------&echo    !a4! ^| !a5! ^| !a6!&echo    ----------&echo    !a7! ^| !a8! ^| !a9!&echo(
choice /c 123456789 /m "!pl!'s turn"
set ch=!errorlevel!
if !ch! equ 0 exit /b
if "!gone:%ch%=!" neq "%gone%" echo That spot has been taken, try again & timeout /t 3 /NOBREAK >nul & goto :play
set "gone=%gone%!ch!"
goto :eof
```

Comment: The first point I saw in your solution is that you use VT100 Esc-sequences to move the cursor. This means that this program does not work in versions previous to Windows 10...

Comment: @Aacini, sure, but that can be removed and the map can be built with `echo & echo` etc.

Comment: I invite you to review the new method I posted in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

For the task of testing, string substitution can be used with variables to test a list of winning cell combinations concisely.

```
@Echo off & CHCP 65001 > nul
 Set LF=^

%= Above empty line required =%
 For /l %%i in (1 1 9)Do Set c%%i=_
 Set Screen=Player: !Player!!LF!!LF! [!c7!][!c8!][!c9!]!LF! [!c4!][!c5!][!c6!]!LF! [!c1!][!c2!][!c3!]!LF!
 Set state=!c1!!c2!!c3!,!c1!!c4!!c7!,!c1!!c5!!c9!,!c4!!c5!!c6!,!c7!!c8!!c9!,!c7!!c5!!c3!,!c3!!c6!!c9!,!c2!!c5!!c8!

 Set "p1=X" & Set "p2=O"
 Set /A "choices=123456789","Move=0","p%p1%%p1%%p1%=1","p%p2%%p2%%p2%=2"

 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & For /l %%m in (1 1 9)Do (
    Set /A "player=((%%m-1) %% 2)+1"
    cls & Echo(%Screen%
    For /f "Delims=" %%e in ('Choice /n /c:!choices!')Do (
        Set "choices=!choices:%%e=!"
            For %%i in (!player!)Do Set "c%%e=!p%%i!"
    )
        cls & Echo(%Screen%
    If %%m GTR 4 (
        Set "test=%State%"
        For %%i in (!p1!!p1!!p1! !p2!!p2!!p2!)Do if not "!test:%%i=!"=="!test!" (
            Echo(player !p%%i! won
            Goto:Eof
 )  )   )
 Echo(draw & Endlocal
```