# else if being inconsistent

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've been making a simple tic-tac-toe game wherein to check whether a player crossed out a row I've made the following logic:

```
::board
echo    %one% ^| %two% ^| %three%
echo    ---------
echo    %four% ^| %five% ^| %six%
echo    ---------
echo    %seven% ^| %eight% ^| %nine%
echo.

::rows

if %one% NEQ - (
    if %one% EQU %two% (
        if %two% EQU %three% (
            goto endGame
        )
    )
) else if %four% NEQ - (
    if %four% EQU %five% (
        if %five% EQU %six% (
            goto endGame
        )
    )
) else if %seven% NEQ - (
    if %seven% EQU %eight% (
        if %eight% EQU %nine% (
            goto endGame
        )
    )
)
```

However, this seems inconsistent as to when the rows including ***one-two-three*** & ***four-five-six*** get crossed off, the game ends, although for the final row the logic fails.

A similar inconsistency follows for the columns.

Can someone help me understand why so?

Comment: This isn't the actual code but is only for reference of the problem

Comment: It's nice that you reduced the code for us. Could you please make it a [mre] as well? I.e. set the variables in a way that it fails. I assume I need something like `set seven=o`, `set eight=o` and `set nine=o`. I assume that this would also end the game. Furthermore I think you should just omit the `else` keywords, but I'd like to be sure about that before I give an answer.

Comment: Are you noticing that when `%one%` does equal `-`, nothing else is being checked at all? And same thing if `%four%` equals `-` then the third row isn't checked.

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70259600/tic-tac-toe-batch-game/70273080#70273080) on a tic-tac-toe game.

Comment: Well, you have provided more code now, but that's a lot of code which is not specific to the problem. It might be reproducible now (but you don't give us the necessary input), but it's no longer minimal. The code should be both, a [mre].

Comment: Your code may be reduced to: `if %one% NEQ - ( %one% equ %two% equ %three% endGame ) else if %four% NEQ - ( %four% etc... ) else if %seven% NEQ - ( %seven% etc... )`. This means: **IF %one% NEQ -** then do the following: **IF one,two,three are the same** endGame, **ELSE** (IF one,two,three are different) **DO NOTHING ADDITIONAL** and end the full structure. Why? Because in the first IF the "then" part was already executed. If you want to check for `%four%` when one,two,three are different, then you need to "un-nest" the three if's and write they independent of each other.

Comment: PS - You may check if one,two,three are the same in just one IF this way: `if %one%%two% equ %two%%three% ...`

Comment: or `if %one%%two%%three% == --- goto endGame` to check the whole first row in one go. Nice and readable - one code line per line/column/diagonal. 8 `if`s needed (3 lines, 3 columns and 2 diagonals) (8 more for the other player`o`). `cmd` doesn't support `if-else-else`. Only one `else` per `if` allowed.

Comment: I've had the `::` trick break complex `IF` statements before.  I think it was only if used within the `IF` statement, but it was a long time ago and my memory is vague on the details.  Try changing to using a proper `REM` for comments.